# Issue with passing accents to a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure, diacritics

If I run this query in a stored procedure, the matching rows are correctly returned

```
select brand from article where brand regexp '[àéëË]';
```

But if I try to transform this into a dynamic statement like

```
set @s=concat('select brand from article where brand regexp \'[',argument,']\'');
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
```

then it fails when I pass 'àéëË' as an argument to the procedure (no matching row found). But it works with no accent ('aeE').

[edit] It doesn't even work with a hard coded value

```
set @s=concat('select brand from article where brand regexp \'[àéëË]\'');
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [11.1 Character Set Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html) in your table.

I can't reproduce the problem with the character sets and collation used in the table:

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_article`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_article` (
    ->     `brand` VARCHAR(255)
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `_article`
    ->     (`brand`)
    -> VALUES
    ->     ('àéëË'),
    ->     ('aeE');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test` (`index` TINYINT, `argument` VARCHAR(255))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT ', `index`, ' `index`, `brand`
    '>                      FROM `_article`
    '>                      WHERE `brand` REGEXP \'[', `argument`, ']\'');
    ->     PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    ->     EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->     SET @`query` := NULL;
    ->     DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(1, 'àéëË');
+-------+----------+
| index | brand    |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | àéëË     |
+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(2, 'e');
+-------+-------+
| index | brand |
+-------+-------+
|     2 | aeE   |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(3, 'á');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(4, 'A');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_test`(5, 'Ë');
+-------+----------+
| index | brand    |
+-------+----------+
|     5 | àéëË     |
+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Example in [Rextester](http://rextester.com/JNSTA32734).